# subset matrix from a list

Tags: r, subset

I have been trying to subset a matrix where rownames are in this format - "chr8:56979853-56987069_RPS20_ENSG00000008988.5"

And I tried to subset like so;

```
include_list <- c("RPS20", "VIL1", "KRT20", "CLDN7")
goi <- subset(mat2, rownames(mat2) %like% include_list)
```

However it errs as the pattern takes only the first element. Is there a way to subset by a list of elements. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look for questions about "search for patterns in strings". You can do something like `subset(mat2, grepl(pattern = paste(include_list, collapse = "|"), x = rownames(mat2))`.

Comment: `grep` is one option through with gene names be careful of situations like "cdc2" and "cdc28". Another option is to split the rowname extract the gene name then do the match. `subset(mat2, sapply(strsplit(rownames(mat2), "_"), "[[", 2) %in% include_list))`

Comment: This worked - goi <- subset(expr, grepl(pattern = paste(include_list, collapse = "|"), x = rownames(expr)))

Answer (score 1):

```
out <- c()
for (x in include_list) {
  check_each <- rownames(mat2)[rownames(mat2) %like% include_list]
  out <- c(out, check_each)
}
goi <- subset(mat2, rownames(mat2) %in% out)
```

note that %like% is from the DescTools package, or you can use base R:

```
out <- c()
for (x in include_list) {
  check_each <- rownames(mat2)[grepl(x, rownames(mat2))]
  out <- c(out, check_each)
}
goi <- subset(mat2, rownames(mat2) %in% out)
```

Comment: OP needs to search within the string, not find exact matches.

Comment: Also mention what package you are using `%like%` from, it's not in Base.